# Write down the complete list of abelian groups with 360 elements

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Here is what I got:

$C_{360}; C_{180}\times C_{2};C_{90}\times C_{2}\times C_{2};C_{120}\times C_{3};C_{60}\times C_{6}$

I thought I would get much more but I got these so far. Is there something I miss?To me it doesn't seem so though

I guess there is a misundertanding I have

I choose my abelian groups according to this:

$C_{n_1}\times C_{n_2}\times C_{n_3}\times...\times C_{n_r} $

such that $n_1$ is divisible by $n_2$, $n_2$ is divisible by $n_3$, $n_3$ is divisible by $n_4$, $n_{r-1}$ is divisible by $n_r$ and so on..

Comment: What about $C_{30}\times C_6\times C_2$?

Comment: See the [Fundamental Theorem of Abelian Groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_abelian_group#Classification), used implicitly in all answers

Comment: Yeah, I missed that one only@BobJones

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have most, but not all. Note, as I think you have, that $360= 2^3*3^2*5$.

I think one thing that you're missing is that $C_2 \times C_2$ is not isomorphic to $C_4$ -in the latter group we have an element of order 4, and no such elements in the former group.

We thus have 3 non-isomorphic groups of order $8=2^3$: $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$, $C_2 \times C_4$, and $C_8$. We have 2 non-isomorphic groups of order $9=3^2$: $C_3 \times C_3$, and $C_9$. And we have a single group of order 5, $C_5$.

Our different groups of order 360 then should be all of the possible combinations of the above groups, one from each order, giving us 6 groups:

- $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2 \times C_3 \times C_3 \times C_5 \cong C_{30} \times C_6 \times C_2$
- $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2 \times C_9 \times C_5 \cong C_{90} \times C_2 \times C_2$
- $C_2 \times C_4 \times C_3 \times C_3 \times C_5 \cong C_{60} \times C_6$
- $C_2 \times C_4 \times C_9 \times C_5 \cong C_{180} \times C_2$
- $C_8 \times C_3 \times C_3 \times C_5 \cong C_{120} \times C_3$
- $C_8 \times C_9 \times C_5 \cong C_{360}$

Comment: Can you check my edit please? I think we are actually saying the same thing because after some of you answered my question I thought I was doing it in wrong way, however now I see that you got the same groups with me, of course I missed one of them.

Comment: Okay, so you've chosen to write them in term of their invariant factors, which is totally fine - but it looks like you are still missing $C_{30} \times C_6 \times C_2$. Personally, I find working with elementary divisors a little bit easier to make sure I'm getting every possible option (so the way I've written the groups on the left side of the bullets), but either way is fine!

Comment: I thought this kind of representation is the aim of the exercise. That's why I've done it this way, of course your way is what I always do. They have done some exercises like this in the book and I thought I should do this way too, I didn't know these two ways are equally correct.

Comment: So it turns out that if $\gcd(m,n) = 1$, then $C_m \times C_n \cong C_{mn}$, which is what justifies the two methods being equivalent (try, for example, writing out the elements in $C_2 \times C_3$ and $C_6$ and find the isomorphism between them). You may have seen this referred to as the Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups, which has a version for elementary divisors, and another version for invariant factors. Even when I'm asked to find the invariant factors I find the elementary divisors first, usually!

Answer (score 8):

First, factorize $360 = 2^3\cdot 3^2 \cdot 5$. Recall that $C_{nm}\cong C_n\times C_m$ if $n$ and $m$ are coprime. This excludes a lot of possibilities. And looking at the partitions of the exponents, we have $$\begin{align} &\color{red}{C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2} \times \color{blue}{C_3 \times C_3} \times \color{darkgreen}{C_5} \cong C_{30} \times C_6 \times C_2\\ & \underline{\color{red}{C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2} \times \color{blue}{C_9} \times \color{darkgreen}{C_5}} \cong C_{90} \times C_2 \times C_2 \\ & \color{red}{C_2 \times C_4} \times \color{blue}{C_3 \times C_3} \times \color{darkgreen}{C_5} \cong C_{60}\times C_3 \times C_2 \cong C_{60}\times C_6 \\ &\underline{\color{red}{C_2 \times C_4}\times \color{blue}{C_9} \times \color{darkgreen}{C_5}} \cong C_{180} \times C_2 \\ & \color{red}{C_8} \times \color{blue}{C_3 \times C_3} \times \color{darkgreen}{C_5}\cong C_{120}\times C_3 \\ & \color{red}{C_8} \times \color{blue}{C_9} \times \color{darkgreen}{C_5}\cong C_{360}.\end{align}$$The equivalences in the right side are obtained gluing together the largest of each color group, one of each, and repeating until there are no factors left.

Answer (score 4):

It is always better to write the prime factorization of the number given first. $$360=2^33^25^1$$
By using this factorization, we can list the abelian groups of order $360$ efficiently, that are
(i) $C_{2^3}\times C_{3^2}\times C_5 $
(ii) $C_{2^3}\times C_3\times C_3\times C_5$
(iii) $C_{2^2}\times C_2\times C_{3^2}\times C_5 $
(iv) $C_{2^2}\times C_2\times C_3\times C_3\times C_5$
(v) $C_2\times C_2\times C_2\times C_{3^2}\times C_5$
(vi) $C_2\times C_2\times C_2\times C_3\times C_3\times C_5$

You can check the number of abelian groups of order $360$ by calculating the product of number of partitions of number $3,2,1$ in the prime factorization.

To write those abelian groups in the form that you desired, you can "group" those cyclic groups with different primes as follows:
$$C_2\times C_2\times C_2\times C_3\times C_3\times C_5 \cong (C_2\times C_3\times C_5)\times (C_2\times C_3)\times C_2\cong C_{30}\times C_6\times C_2$$
It would be a good practice for you to write the rest of those abelian groups in similar form.

Comment: but in $C_{8}\times C_{9}\times C_{5}  ,5\nmid 9, $  similarly $9 \nmid 8$  same thing happens in other groups you wrote

Comment: @LeylaAlkan editted.